# force shutdown java socket

Tags: java, sockets, bind

I have develop a simple master/slave application but I have this error

java bind exception address already in use

if the server don't close properly. 
How can I force the shutdown of the binded socket?

Comment: can you please post the code that causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

Handle the exception(s):

```
try {
    serverSocket.bind(...);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("bind failed: " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(10);
}
```